# How to make seaborn joint plots faster?

Tags: python, seaborn, jointplot

I am trying to make a 2D plot with a bivariate density graph with seaborn. Basically, it shows the density of the joint occurrence of two variables in the 2D plane, like the image show below

[image]

The x and y data for this plot are stored in a dataframe df with columns 'x' and 'y'.

I am able to get this with seaborn using

```
sns.jointplot(data=df, x=df['x'], y=df['y'], kind = 'kde', fill = True)
```

However, I find that this plot gets very slow as the size of df increases. Are there any ways to make this plot faster in seaborn?

Comment: It should be `g = sns.jointplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', kind = 'kde', fill = True)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the plot faster, why not average the data over short intervals which would reduce the dataset by the factor of n (n being the number of datapoints a window will average)

For example: `data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
Averaging by the window size of 2, the data will look like this:

```
data = [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5]
```